# Compare each obs with rest of its sub-group

Tags: stata

I have the following goal regarding my data structure

```
group; month; year; next_year
1; February; 2014; 0
1; March; 2006; 0
1; November; 2013; 1
2; January; 2014; 0
3; January; 2004; 0
```

I do have `group`, `month` and `year`, however the column `next_year` needs to be generated from the first three: For each observation, I want to check if there is another observation within the same group that has a date-value which falls into the period of next year. If so, I want to set the value of `next_year` to 1, otherwise to 0 (see example).

I started by converting the date into a format that Stata can interpret - using `ym(month, year)` - such that I can make comparisons. However, I am not sure how to iterate over all observations within the group in order to determine if that is the case or not.

I would know how to do it in e.g. Java, but I don't for Stata. I suppose I should not start with loops as there are probably some implemented commands for such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if there is a following observation within the next 12 months, you can try:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input group str8 month year
1 March 2006 
1 March 2013 
1 November 2013 
1 January 2013
2 January 2014 
3 January 2004 
end 

*----- what you want -----

gen dat = monthly(month + string(year), "MY") 
format dat %tm  

bysort group (dat): gen next = dat[_n+1] - dat <= 12

list, sepby(group)
```

Make sure you understand the difference between Nick's code and mine. They work under different assumptions. You can check the differences running both pieces of code with the data I have provided (originally Nick's but with one observation deleted to get the point across; by chance, if you use Nick's data without the modification, the results will be the same).

Comment: Thanks, Roberto! I implemented Nick's code with pretty much the same logic you applied in your example...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in avoiding an explicit loop. This kind of problem is soluble using `by:`.

I modified your example to have two observations for one group in one year.

```
clear 

input group str8 month year
1 February 2014 
1 March 2006 
1 March 2013 
1 November 2013 
2 January 2014 
3 January 2004 
end 

bysort group (year) : gen next_year = year[_n+1] == year + 1 
bysort group year (next_year) : replace next_year = next_year[_N]

list, sepby(group)  

     +------------------------------------+
     | group      month   year   next_y~r |
     |------------------------------------|
  1. |     1      March   2006          0 |
  2. |     1   November   2013          1 |
  3. |     1      March   2013          1 |
  4. |     1   February   2014          0 |
     |------------------------------------|
  5. |     2    January   2014          0 |
     |------------------------------------|
  6. |     3    January   2004          0 |
     +------------------------------------+
```

Getting an explicit `sort` order is essential. Within `group`, we look ahead to see if the next `year` is the current `year` plus 1, assigning 1 if true and 0 if false. That will at most be true for the last observation for a given `group` and `year`. If there is more than one observation for each group and year, any occurrence of 1 must be spread to all such observations.

For a tutorial on `by:`, see [Speaking Stata: How to move step by: step](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0004).

The assumption here is that you mean in the next calendar year, not in the next 12 months. Making your dates into Stata monthly dates will be needed for most other problems, but doesn't make this one easier. Here is one way to do that in your situation, assuming that `month` is string and `year` is numeric:

```
gen mdate = monthly(month + string(year), "MY") 
format mdate %tm
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick. I implemented the 12 months logic with your hint. As well, thank you for the link, the reading will be worthwhile I guess! `bysort group (year): gen next_year = ( monthly(month[_n+1] + string(year[_n+1]), "MY") < monthly(month + string(year+1), "MY")  )`

Comment: @Justus, one fundamental problem with your solution is that sorting by `group year` does not uniquely identify observations within your data set. That makes your results non-reproducible and so pretty much worthless (and if worth-some, only by chance). If you run the code several times, you will see this is the case. Style is another "issue"; I would not consider nesting functions like you have done good style, but again, it's only style. It makes the code harder to follow (for me at least).

Comment: Note that in Nick's code, the sorting issue is immaterial.

Comment: The relevant reference for that problem is: www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0019.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer: I do see your point! Thank you for pointing it out again, I changed the code accordingly.

Comment: Now that the problem has been clarified as definitely within the next 12 months, the only good way to solve it is to create a monthly date variable and look with observations within 12 months, as within @RobertoFerrer's code. The formulation of the question is still fuzzy.